# Login and signup screens are shown but I have already logged in

Tags: support, login

> The Login screen is shown but I have already logged in to this website.

Please click this link for signup screen shown, but I'm already logged in.

**https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/signup**

and same as the login screens are shown

**https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add**

Is it correct? I think this may be a bug.

Answer (score 2):

No, these are not bugs.

There is no reason to completely hide these pages if you are already logged in.

If you go to the signup page (which is not linked from the header when logged in), it means you **meant** to go there. And you can sign up again.

And, you will note that the login-add page allows you to add another credential to the logged in account - this is certainly by design.